# How to add class to an element using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<section id="menu">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
                <h2>Dynamic</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="items">
                <li><i class="fad fa-chart-pie-alt"></i><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-uikit"></i><a href="#">UI Elements</a></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i><a href="#">Tables</a></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-cc-visa"></i><a href="#">Cards</a></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-hamburger"></i><a href="#">Modal</a></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><a href="#">Blank</a></li>
            </div>
        </section>

const checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");

checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("dark");
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark");
});
```

I tried using document.getElementById("h2").className += "dark";

but nothing is happening, what am i doing wrong

Comment: You don't have an element with the id "h2".

Comment: You could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `getElementByid` (if the `h2` element you want is the *first* one in the document). Separately, if you did it by appending to `className`, you'd probably need a space before `dark`. But these days, use `.classList.add("dark")` instead.

Comment: try this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_remove_class

Comment: There is not element with id "h2".

[Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is use to get which as a specific `id` and there should only be on element with that given **ID**

Answer (score 0):

it should work like you wished but be aware of that it will find every H2 element and it will change them.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("H2");
for (var step = 0; step < elements.length; step++) {
  elements[step].classList.add("dark");
}
```